# See requests to real server with mod_proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, awstats, mod-cache

My setup involves using apache with mod_cache and mod_proxy to proxy and cache xml data between my iOS app and a web service. Right now I'm using awstats to see how many requests my iOS app is making to my proxy server. Is there any way to see stats (or just a number) of the requests that are actually being made to the web service's server?

Here's a diagram of the server setup for clarity:

iOS app <-----> My caching proxy server <-----> Web service

Note that I don't have access to the web service's server other than to interact with the web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a way to do with Apache's debug logging module (mod_forensic), but it's going to generate much more logging information than you need, and you're almost certainly going to have write a log parser and filtering routine to do it.

The simplest solution is to configure a second non-caching proxy server on the same machine (it can even be the same Apache configuration, listening on loopback), have it log its requests to a separate set of log files, and then have the caching proxy server proxy to that server rather than the backend web service.  So your new setup will look like:

```
iOS app <-> [caching proxy server <-> non-caching proxy server] <-> web service
```

The requests will be local, so you won't add too much in the way of latency, but you will end up using more Apache resources, so configure appropriately.

Comment: This seems like it would be the simplest way to do it. Thanks for the help!